# Is "all types of" a combination?

Tags: meaning

I am aware of the noun phrase "type of", though I am not sure when I am supposed to use "all types of".

[google](https://www.google.com/search?bih=598&biw=1280&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&hl=en&sxsrf=ACYBGNSViUVNbpCoi2j9wM0bhZlYuTbdnQ%3A1581862137286&ei=-UxJXoyGEcm_0PEPtNCQ2AI&q=meaning%20of%20%22all%20types%20of%22) gives lots of results about "all types of", for instance,

> Oranges, apples, pears and bananas are all types of fruit.

Is "all types of" a combination? or just a ordinary expression.

I guess the rewritten version (my version) has the same meaning

> All of oranges, apples, pears and bananas are types of fruit.

Though my version seems a little bit strange.

Comment: At a pinch, ***all types of fruit*** could be interpreted as a multi-word "noun phrase", meaning the ***totality** of all possible types of fruit **collectively*** (a "totally inclusive" np). But because it would be an "unusual" sense, we'd probably choose to express that meaning more explicitly, perhaps as *all the different types of fruit **which exist***. Essentially, it's a matter of whether ***all*** in the cited context attaches to ***Oranges, apples, pears*** (the "default" interpretation), or to ***types of fruit*** (my "contrived" interpretation here).

Comment: @FF I thought about the potential ambiguity in "all types" as well, but, because interpreting "all" as modifying "types" results in nonsense (the specific fruits listed do not exhaust the class of fruits), I decided to ignore addressing that potential ambiguity explicitly and merely express my preference for "each a type of."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version is not idiomatic.

I do not know what you mean by "combination." "Type of [generic noun]" is a very common phrase, but "type" can be used outside of that phrase as can "of" and generic nouns.

> Oranges, apples, pears, and bananas are all types of fruit

uses "all" in an idiomatic way to stress that each noun in the subject is one type of fruit. I'd prefer to say that

> Oranges, apples, pears, and bananas are each a type of fruit

But both are simply long-winded ways to say

> Oranges, apples, pears, and bananas are different types of fruit

or even more succinctly

> Oranges, apples, pears, and bananas are fruits.

Comment: You could use 'both' if only two types of something were mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

*All types of fruit* is a perfectly good expression, in, for example,

> I eat dairy, vegetables, and all types of fruit.

But in your example,

> Oranges, apples, pears and bananas are all types of fruit,

though it is a perfectly good sentence, it does not contain *all types of fruit* as a constituent. I'm not sure how best to analyse *all* there but whatever it is, it modifies the subject (*oranges, apples, pears and bananas*), not the complement (*types of fruit*).